# Piping Stdout of One NodeJS Process to Another

Tags: node.js, logging, stream, stdout, stdin

I have this code

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
(function(){
    exec('node ../../service2.js', function(err, stdout, stderr){
        stdout.pipe(process.stdin);
        process.stdout.write(process.stdin);
    });
})();
```

I'm trying to have it so I only have one service in a cluster logging.  For some reason this won't write the other streams' logs.  Is there something that I'm missing such as a read from stdin? I'd like to pipe as much as I can together.